# Graph Plot in JFreeChart

Tags: logging, scale, jfreechart

On the X axis my data points(20 of them) take values between 0 and 0.2. My X axis should have range from 0 to 1. 
On the Y axis corresponding values are between 0.8 and 0.86. When I plot this graph using NumberAxis in JFreeChart I get very dense graph especially in the interval X belongs to 0.01 to 0.02.(so I can't see much)
Is it meaningful to use log scale for X axis in this case? How should I adjust LogAxis in JFreeChart here?

Answer (score 1):

To use [`LogAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/LogAxis.html), just create the axis and set it as the plot's domain:

```
LogAxis xAxis = new LogAxis("X");
plot.setDomainAxis(xAxis);
```

`LogAxisDemo1`, shown among the *XY Charts* in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), is a complete example. [`LogarithmicAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/LogarithmicAxis.html) may be a more visually appealing alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Using log scale for x-coordinates is sensible. One approach without trying to figure out the right syntax for LogAxis is to transform the data points from `{x, y}` to `{log(x), y}` and use the normal linear scale charting.