# How to scale data on Chart for better view when ranges of ages are very different?

Tags: java, swing, charts, visualization, jfreechart

I'm trying to visualize computer performance data using Java Swing and [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).
On one chart I want to show CPU load (%) and user memory by some process. So, the possible values for CPU are 0..100, but for memory: from 10KB (10*1024b) to 500MB (500*1024*1024b), the difference is big.

What is the best way to present that data? 
Thank you!

Comment: It depends on your values distribution and what can of values you want to make salient. I think I would try a logarithmic scale for that since you are probably looking for peaks in memory usage.

Comment: More on logarithmic axes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8590079/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this will be a graph which is has time on the X axis and performance metric on the Y axis.

This being the case, I would display the memory as % of memory used instead of the number of (kilo|mega|giga)bytes in use.  This way it could be overlaid on the CPU (and other performance metrics) without distorting the overall scale.

I no longer have a copy of the developer guide (this must be purchased from JFree.org) but as I recall, JFreeChart offers a way to add a tool-tip to points on a line graph.  You could use this to provide the user a way to see the (kilo|mega|giga)bytes in use if they were interested in more than just the % of memory used.