# What is the maximum range value of TimeSeriesChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

If I create a `TimeSeriesChart`, when I set the first Y `NumberAxis` value to `2147483647`, it cannot be shown in the chart. But when I set the first value to `2` for example, and then set the second value to `2147483647`, it *can* be shown in the chart.
Why this happend, and how to resolve it? Is this about the max value of Y?

Answer (score 1):

The constant `2147483647` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. When the minimum value exceeds zero, the default, axis scaling does *not* overflow; otherwise it *does*. If your data really includes such a large dynamic range, consider a logarithmic axis: `LogAxis` is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353270/230513), and `LogarithmicAxis` is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8590079/230513).